# Rails Rspec logging in with selected user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm facing the problem with logging in rspec with selected user. I've tried making controller module like that:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login(user)
    before(:each) do
      @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      payload = { jti: SecureRandom.uuid, sub: user.id.to_s }
      cookies['access_token'] = JWT.encode(payload, ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY'], 'HS256')
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is that I'm either unbale to pass user in situation like that:

```
    context 'as admin' do
      let(:user) { create :user, :super_admin }
      login user

      before do 
        get :index
      end

      it { expect(response).to be_ok }
    end
```

and i get:[image]

Or if I try something like that:

```
    context 'as admin' do
      let(:user) { create :user, :super_admin }

      before do 
        login user
        get :index
      end
      
      it { expect(response).to be_ok }
    end
```

I get:
[image]

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created `login` helper with `before(:each)` block

In the first case, where you are calling `login` helper outside the `it` or `before` block and passing `user` instance created using `let`. here `user` is not available as scope of `let` variables is inside the `it` or `before` block.

In the second case, where you are calling `login` helper inside the `before` block, but `login` helper also adds `before(:each)` block. I suspect due to calling of `before(:each)` within `before` it raises the error. similar issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56815131/rspec-login-user-issue)

**Possible solutions**

1. create `user` inside the `login` helper and call it outside the `it` block

   ```
      module ControllerMacros
       def login
         before(:each) do
           user = create :user, :super_admin
           @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
           payload = { jti: SecureRandom.uuid, sub: user.id.to_s }
           cookies['access_token'] = JWT.encode(payload, ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY'], 'HS256')
           sign_in user
         end
       end
     end

     context 'as admin' do
       login

       before do 
         get :index
       end

       it { expect(response).to be_ok }
     end
   ```
2. Remove `before(:each)` block from `login` helper

   ```
      module ControllerMacros
       def login(user)
         @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
         payload = { jti: SecureRandom.uuid, sub: user.id.to_s }
         cookies['access_token'] = JWT.encode(payload, ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY'], 'HS256')
         sign_in user
       end
     end

     context 'as admin' do
       let(:user) { create :user, :super_admin }

       before do 
         login user
         get :index
       end

       it { expect(response).to be_ok }
     end
   ```